# How to save response time to a file

Tags: jmeter

How to save response time from view results tree to a file? 
this listener has option to export result file to a path, but the output doesn't contain the response time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use listeners when it comes to load testing, [they don't add any value and in the same time they consume extra resources](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing).

[Run your test in command-line non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) like:

```
jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
```

Once your test finishes open the `result.jtl` file with your favorite text editor or any other application capable of opening CSV files like [LibreOffice Calc](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/calc/). The "response time" you are looking for is `elapsed` column, the value is in milliseconds.

[image: JMeter Elapsed]

See [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) guide for more information and recommendations for JMeter configuration for the best performance